Connection refused when requesting the server. AWS Lightsail
I created a MEAN instance. I created and bound my own domain to the static IP address of my instance. I downloaded the next.js project. It is configured to open on port 3000. Added virtual hosts
  <VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/htdocs/prolisok-fe"
    <Directory "/home/bitnami/htdocs/prolisok-fe">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
  </VirtualHost>

Also for https
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAlias *
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
    DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/htdocs/prolisok-fe"
    <Directory "/home/bitnami/htdocs/prolisok-fe">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
  </VirtualHost>

Also added a Let's Encrypt certificate with sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool
Frontend works well, but the problem is connecting the backend in Java
I created a new directory, downloaded the jar file, ran it on port 8080, but when I make a request, I get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED


Both projects are run using the pm2 utility. in their configurations, they are set to run on localhost on their ports.
I suspect that the problem is that I haven't configured the redirection and VirtualHost for the backend correctly, but I haven't found instructions for this anywhere
However, if you make a request inside the Bitnami console, everything is fine
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/contact \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"name": "Test", "phone": "+380000000000", "message": "Lorem input text"}'

What are the ways to fix the situation and get the data? the error is definitely not in CORS, that's why CORS is disabled on the backend
